# mySQL transfer autoincrement data to another table using vb,net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to transfer my clientid data in clients table to item table? My clientid is autoincrement

Here is my code

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into item (clientid, type, gram, karat, date_added, description) values('" & txtType.Text & "','" & txtGram.Text & "','" & txtKarat.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker_DOB.Text & "','" & txtDesc.Text & "') select clientid from clients"
```

Comment: Probably clientId is an autoincrement column in the client table not in the item table, so you just need to read it from your client table and insert into your item table. Said that take a look at parameterized queries

Comment: I'm kinda new to queries, can you display what will I need to do in my problem?

Comment: @Taengoo Kim , first you must put your code, and we will try to help you.. autoincrement is a Primary Key function by default in a table. I think you must copy your desired data from Clients table to Item table ..  but without code how can you understant what you want ?  And use Google : mySQL copy records